# CSS functions in Django app, but cannot edit it anymore

Tags: css, django

I'm having quite the weird issue. My Django (1.10) app is functioning just fine. I initially set it up using bootstrap with my own style.css file to customize the rest of it. However, since then I've had some issues and lost my git commits, so I can only go back to about 10 days ago when it was stable in production. I thought all was well until I tried to style some new pages and change some existing css, and then I found I couldn't.

My app seems to have style.css files all over the place. There seems to be 4 total, and none of them do anything. I've tried deleting everything from each one individually, and then deleting everything from all of them at once, but no matter what my site stays with its styling. I've cleared the cache from my browser, used a different browser, used incognito mode, etc. No matter what, the styles persist. I initially used collectstatic. Now, I've tried to do it again, and I've also tried collectstatic --clear, but both have the same effect: my root static folder gets an entire copy of my app put in it and I have to delete the changes with git.

[Here's a link to the github page for it.](https://github.com/technicallyrice27/translation-site) And I'll post some relevent snippets below. Please let me know if any other information will make it easier to help, and I will be happy to provide it.

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Top of my base.html file which every other template derives from (note the last two lines):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="divTheme" class="light-theme">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>OP Translations</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'translations/style.css' %}" />
```

When I run collectstatic, it tells me the files will be collected in the top level static folder, but that is one of the files that does nothing when I change it.

I'm not really sure what else to post, so please let me know. All the existing posts on this question say its a browser cache issue, but for some reason that doesn't work here. I must have something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I can't write a comment to ask something but i think that you edit the wrong style.css file.
I take a look in your Github project and found out that the style.css in https://github.com/technicallyrice27/translation-site/tree/master/translations/static/translations was not updated since 11 days.

but this is the file you need to edit when using the collectstatic command.

Hope this help you.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but I've tried editing this file (not using a commit, just locally) and unfortunately it doesn't change anything. I don't think any of the style.css files have had a commit recently, as changes to them don't work anyway so I've had to resort to quick inline styles in the meantime until I can figure this out.

Comment: hmm... ok, maybe it is another error. I found that you have many "style.css" files with different template and static folders https://github.com/technicallyrice27/translation-site/tree/master/translations/static/translations/static/translations

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately after trying to change them all, I found not a single one of the style.css files actually does anything.